# How to perform equal-to comparison on multiple columns in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to create a method for querying a table in Realm with the option for excluding certain rows (by their IDs). Since Realm doesn't support multiple equal parameters similar to its `findAllSorted(String[], boolean[])` method, I'm performing it in a loop.

Is there a better way to do this job?

```
public static RealmResults<MessageItem> getAll(long threadId, Collection<Long> excludedMessageIds) {

        final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<MessageItem> allMessagesQuery = realm.where(MessageItem.class);

        // Apply conditions
        // 1. Thread to look into
        if (threadId != -1)
            allMessagesQuery = allMessagesQuery.equalTo(MessageItem.COLUMN_THREAD_ID, threadId);

        // 2. Message IDs to exclude
        for (final Long excludedMessageId : excludedMessageIds) {

            allMessagesQuery = allMessagesQuery.notEqualTo(
                    MessageItem.COLUMN_MESSAGE_ID,
                    excludedMessageId
            );

        }

        return allMessagesQuery.findAll();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such method like that. Probably you could try to add field like `private boolean excluded` and set it to true where you exclude your messages. Then query all like this

```
return realm.where(MessageItem.class)                
            .equalTo(MessageItem.COLUMN_THREAD_ID, threadId);
            .equalTo(MessageItem.COLUMN_EXCLUDED, false);
            .findAll();
```

Comment: Adding unnecessary columns for every column I want to exclude would be a terrible choice. Is there anything wrong in adding notEqualTo() multiple times?

Comment: @Saket, I think it depends on count of your messages. In my opinion this is better way have additional column instead of doing too much queries